# Unexpected token ; Emberfire not installing with ember-cli

Tags: node.js, ember.js, firebase, emberfire

I have been breaking my head on installing emberfire to set up a backend and database for working with my front end ember app. I cleaned up node_modules, did a fresh npm install and also did npm cache clean. Gave up trying to fix it.

When i run,

`$ ember install emberfire`

i am getting below error.

```
Installed packages for tooling via npm.
Unexpected token ;
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Project.require (C:\Users\vignesh\Documents\Developer\MyTechStack\library-ember-app\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\project.js:285:12)
    at Project.config (C:\Users\vignesh\Documents\Developer\MyTechStack\library-ember-app\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\project.js:201:26)
    at CoreObject.extend.install (C:\Users\vignesh\Documents\Developer\MyTechStack\library-ember-app\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\blueprint.js:435:34)
```

Steps i tried till now

- Cleaned the node_modules and did npm install again.
- Installed ember-cli globally.
- Cleared the cache.

My package.json looks like this

```
{
  "name": "library-ember-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Small description for library-ember-app goes here",
  "private": true,
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc",
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ember build",
    "start": "ember server",
    "test": "ember test"
  },
  "repository": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.10.0"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.4.2",
    "ember-ajax": "^2.0.1",
    "ember-cli": "2.7.0",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-babel": "^5.1.6",
    "ember-cli-bootstrap-sassy": "0.5.3",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^1.2.0",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "^1.0.3",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^0.3.1",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.4.0",
    "ember-cli-jshint": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "^2.0.0",
    "ember-cli-release": "^0.2.9",
    "ember-cli-sass": "5.4.0",
    "ember-cli-sri": "^2.1.0",
    "ember-cli-test-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "ember-data": "^2.7.0",
    "ember-export-application-global": "^1.0.5",
    "ember-load-initializers": "^0.5.1",
    "ember-resolver": "^2.0.3",
    "ember-welcome-page": "^1.0.1",
    "emberfire": "2.0.1"
  }
}
```

Bower.json

```
{
  "name": "library-ember-app",
  "dependencies": {
    "ember": "~2.7.0",
    "ember-cli-shims": "0.1.1",
    "ember-qunit-notifications": "0.1.0",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "firebase": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Which version of `ember-cli` are you using in your project (and which did you install globally)?

Comment: @JustinNiessner I am using **ember-cli@2.7.0** both locally and global.

Comment: Based on the error, it looks like you have a syntax error in your `environment.js` file.

Comment: Yes i deleted the config folder and ran `ember install emberfire` again. It installed it correctly. Omg dont believe that i spent three days on this. Should i have the config folder within app?

Comment: You're `config` folder should be at the root of the project and have the `environment.js` file in it. Rather than delete it, you should just fix the syntax error.

Comment: For some reason, when i created new app using `ember new "app-name"`, ./config/environment.js file didnt get created. I was under the impression, that installing emberfire will create new environment.js file. When i was trying different things. I created the config folder manually and added some config values from firebase. The values were wrong, so i deleted the whole folder and tried reinstalling using ember-cli.